# Blender doesn't render anything on my laptop

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, light

So I have a decent laptop that used to render perfectly. In fact I'd throw some heavy scenes and it would do just fine. But recently after formatting my laptop, i am getting this weird issue where even the default cube-light set-up doesnt seem to light anything.Please help me out!

This is what the issue looks like..
[image: Nothing is being rendered. Not even in material preview]

Comment: It looks like you have a graphics driver problem after your reformat.  Are you sure you have the right drivers, and that the system settings in blender preferences are enabled for the graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have an AMD GPU in your laptop? Your symptoms look identical to an issue AMD users were having recently regarding the latest Adrenalin drivers. You may be able to correct things by checking (enabling) "High Quality Normals" under *Render Properties > Performance*. If that doesn't work, try rolling your graphics drivers back to an earlier version.

[image: NormalsHQ]